# Replace a command with the result (command output) in the line using sed

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, regular-expression, perl

Is it possible to replace a command extracted by some regex with its output using sed?

For example, I have the next file:

```
2 + 2 = $$shell:echo 2 + 2 | bc$$ // and "some unescaped text' here
```

how I can transform it into:

```
2 + 2 = 4 // and "some unescaped text' here
```

I found that it is possible to extract the command and evaluate it:

```
echo '2 + 2 = $$shell:echo 2 + 2 | bc$$ // and "some unescaped text' here | sed -e 's/.*\$\$shell:\(.*\)\$\$.*/\1/e'
4
```

But I can't understand how to keep the rest part of the line.

Comment: sed it to `echo "2 + 2 = $(echo 2 + 2 | bc)" ` then exec it. However with this type of thing you are opening a security hole.

Comment: A complete solution is probably not possible with only sed. As I understand, any solution leads to the creation of a string to evaluate in shell. So, I chose the solution in Perl as the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Perl...

```
perl -pe 's[\$\$shell:(.*?)\$\$][ qx($1) =~ s/\n$//r ]ge' < inputfile
```

(`qx` is the equivalent of a command substitution, except it doesn't remove trailing newlines, so the `=~ s/\n$//r` does it. The surrounding `s[][]ge` is just a usual substitution with a Perl expression in the replacement.)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with perl. But your example looks completely solving the problem (even with multiple commands per line, if '.*?' is used in the regex). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but

```
$ echo '2 + 2 = $$shell:echo 2 + 2 | bc$$ // and some text here' | 
  sed -e 's/\(.*\)\$\$shell:\(.*\)\$\$\(.*\)/printf "%s%s%s\n" "\1" "$(sh -c "\2")" "\3"/e'
2 + 2 = 4 // and some text here
```

Comment: Thank you. I found new points about sed in your answer. But main purpose of using a such difficult pattern is to prevent the unexpected evaluation of '$(...)' and to avoid problems with escaping of non-command part of the line (it can contain quotas, for example).